# MySQL - select if no other entry on the same day

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get entry from a table, if "*TIME*" = *1* and no other events (entry) for same "*UNIQ*" occur on the **same day.**

The picture shows the data that should be selected...

[image]

Comment: "`and no other events (entry) for same "UNIQ" occur on the same day.`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM source t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM source t2
                   WHERE t2.data >= DATE(t1.data) 
                     AND t2.data < DATE(t1.data) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                     AND t1.uniq = t2.uniq
                     AND t1.id != t2.id )
  AND `time` = 1
```

Comment: thank you but my database is pretty big, it crashed/hang after this query :(

Comment: @Michal Create according indices.

Comment: @Michal It is strange - the query is simple enough. How many rows there is in your table? Try 2nd variant.

Comment: I added the index to "time" and it's fine (the base currently has over 100,000), but I'm not getting any results, there are many such cases in the database, for example:
https://i.ibb.co/tDwpY33/ext.jpg

Comment: @Michal The unequiation by `id` (it is PK, is it?) added, test pleease. *the base currently has over 100,000* This is small DB in terms of mySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `YOURTABLE` 
       WHERE TIME=1 
       AND UNIQ NOT IN (
           SELECT UNIQ FROM `YOURTABLE` 
              WEHERE TIME=1 
              GROUP BY DATE(DATA) 
              having count(DATE(DATA)) > 1
       )
```

Comment: still not working, I get results on the same day and same uniq